# Browser - SVG rendering completed event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, extjs, dom-events

is there a DOM event that I can use, to see if the rendering of an SVG is completed? I'm adding a SVG dynamically, after retrieving the content via an ajax request.

I'm using ExtJS4 to add the ajax response to a new container like this:

```
    response = MyXMLHttpRequestObjectFromAjaxRequest;
    ...
    this.svgContainer = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
            width:SvgData[this.svgFileName].dimension.width,
            height:SvgData[this.svgFileName].dimension.height,
            autoDestroy:false
        }
    );
    destination.add(this.svgContainer);
    this.svgContainer.update(response.responseText, false);
```

My problem is that it takes some time till the SVG is rendered and the dom becomes accessible for DomQueries etc. I'd need an event that tells me that the dom is ready and that I can start manipulating it?

Comment: Did you find a useful way to determine when drawing/rendering is complete?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to catch the [afterrender](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-afterrender) or [added](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-event-added) event of the container?

Comment: actually not yet! I'll give it a try. I was able to work around this "problem".